# Filtering content of one controller with model in another (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-model

I have something similar to this:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerA">
    <input type="text" id="search_form" value="Search" ng-model="searchModel" />
</div>

<div ng-controller="ControllerB">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchModel">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But when I search in the input bar, it does not impact my list. How can I make my model from one controller impact the content of another?

Thanks.

**Edit**

`ControllerA` and `ControllerB` are entirely isolated of each other and I would like to keep it that way. If I need to share the model with the other controller, how would I use `$rootScope` to do that?

Comment: how are you sharing `searchModel` between controllers?

Comment: I guess that's the question! I didn't realize I had to. When I had the model and content in the same controller, I didn't have anything in the scope, so I didn't realize I would need to share it with the controllers apart. How would I set it up so that it could be shared?

Comment: you can make `ControllerA` the parent controller and `ControllerB` the child controller and then change the variable on `$parent`

Comment: Is there any way I could just get the model to react to the `$rootScope`? I would like to keep the controllers isolated from each other.

Comment: of course, but polluting the `$rootScope` is not a best practice, you should use a service or factory for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `service` to share data between controllers.
Use the [factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) feature which angular has to define the `service`.

Here is an example which i found [here](https://gist.github.com/exclsr/3595424) with and easy google search.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="project">
<head>
    <title>Angular: Service example</title>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script>
var projectModule = angular.module('project',[]);

projectModule.factory('theService', function() {  
    return {
        thing : {
            x : 100
        }
    };
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, theService) {
    $scope.thing = theService.thing;
    $scope.name = "First Controller";
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, theService) {   
    $scope.someThing = theService.thing; 
    $scope.name = "Second Controller!";
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <input ng-model="thing.x"/>         
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <input ng-model="someThing.x"/>             
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a model that needs to be shared you should use a service that way both controller can access the data and be aware of any changes